# Modify array with a method of the same class

Tags: java, oop

i have class Deck

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Deck implements DeckActions{
    private static Card[] cards=new Card[52];
    public Deck () {
        int i=0;                                    
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values()){
            for (Rank rank : Rank.values()){
                cards[i++]=new Card(rank,suit); 
            }
        }
    }

    public Card draw() {                                 
        return cards[0];
    }

    public void shift(int times) {                          
        Random randomGenerator=new Random();
        int card1=randomGenerator.nextInt(52);
        int card2=randomGenerator.nextInt(52);

        for (int counter=0;counter < times; counter++){

        Card temp=new Card(null,null);
        temp=cards[card1];
        cards[card1]=cards[card2];
        cards[card2]=temp;
        }
    }
    public void show() {                            
        for (int i=0;i<cards.length;i++){
            System.out.println(cards[i].toString());    
        }   
    }
}
```

that implements interface

```
public interface DeckActions {

    public Card draw();                 
    public void shift(int times);       
    public void show();                 

}
```

the problem i have is that the Shift method doesn't actually change the deck array.
What am i missing? I really can't figure out.

This is my main class, i tried to call the method with an int like 100, or 52, but show always shows the same array

```
public class TestCard {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Deck deck=new Deck();
            deck.show();
        deck.shift(52);
        System.out.println("Shifted");
        deck.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - you haven't shown how you're calling the method, or any indication that it doesn't actually work.

Comment: As an aside, you do not need to instantiate a `Card` in the line "Card temp=new Card(null, null)". You are just assigning a reference in the next line.

Comment: I'm calling the method in the main class providing an int for the number of times i would like the switch to be done, ie 100

Comment: If you don't have to roll your own shuffle alogrithm: `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cards));`

Comment: i don't have to, but before using built-in functions i would like to implement my own algorithms to check my knowledge, since i'm learning java for 1 week

Comment: Problem is not related to java ,nor oop It's related to your logic .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that lines which generate random indexes of cards to swap are outside loop, so all the time you swap the same 2 cards. 
Try:

```
 public void shift(int times) {                          
    Random randomGenerator=new Random();

    for (int counter=0;counter < times; counter++){

       int card1=randomGenerator.nextInt(52);
       int card2=randomGenerator.nextInt(52);

       Card temp=new Card(null,null);
       temp=cards[card1];
       cards[card1]=cards[card2];
       cards[card2]=temp;
    }
}
```

P.S: any reason for field cards to be static?

Comment: i didn't realize it was outside the loop, i was very tired! thanks :) actually don't, it was a try... i thought i was missing some Java rule about array, methods etc